# React-Native Run-Android Not Working After Upgrading

Tags: android, react-native

I have recently upgraded my app's react-native version to 0.60, and want to run the app on an android emulator to see if everything is working as it should be. When I ran the command react-native run-android I get an error that says: error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. What can I do to successfully run my app?

Comment: What is the ouput of `echo $ANDROID_HOME` ?

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to mention that I am currently on Windows 10, but the output is $ANDROID_HOME.

Comment: On Windows you have to write `echo %ANDROID_HOME%`. Or just make sure that you have Android Studio and environment set up correctly. Anyways I'm not quite sure if this is the problem.

Comment: The output is C:\Ortega\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk. I must mention though that Android Studio and my emulator are indeed setup correctly as everything was working perfectly fine before I upgraded react-native. I am also getting a few warnings when I run the command react-native run-android should I post those?

Comment: Please try this steps by which I am able to run the app, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27157#issuecomment-555838208

Answer (score 0):

below these may clear the issue I guess;

- upgrade NODE and NPM if necessary (this solved my issue)
- gradle clean on android
- delete node modules and re-install npm (since on npm installation there should be no network interruption)
- make sure any of the packages are not linked properly.
- re-open terminal